# Excel MATCH fails even though cells are identical in value and format

Tags: excel

I have some strings, and I'd like to match another string to them.
While I can do this easily with, for example, alphabet characters, `MATCH()` fails when I try my actual list of strings.

I have checked that the lookup-value and the lookup-array are the same format, and a formula like `=E1=D1` returns TRUE between the strings.

About Excel tells me the version is `Version 1801`.

[Here is a link to an MCV example.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YeI3NBAYB_Ae46Y15vZR4xFxlCpz9Dd_/view?usp=sharing) The error in question occurs in cell `E3`.

Comment: Are you trying to match numbers? Are you *sure* that the numbers are properly identified as a number, and not as a string?

Comment: What does your match() look like, what arguments are you passing it?Match(e1,d1,-1) ?

Comment: @JoshAdams your question's led me to the answer: the match() will fail in this situation if the [match_type] is not set to 0, "exact match".  Didn't catch it since a test with simpler strings worked without that argument set.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks ill post the answer if you want to close @Librarian

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the solution is to call `MATCH()` with the "exact match" option for optional argument `match_type`.
`MATCH(B1, A1:A10, 0)` instead of `MATCH(B1, A1:A10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Match is declared: MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type]) Don't forget to declare the match type.